# Sequelize delete instance with n:m and 1:m associations and update Model

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 2 models in my postgresql db and using sequelize and node:

1. Users
2. Transactions

and are associated like this:

```
UserModel.hasMany(TransactionModel, { as: 'sentTransactions', foreignKey: 'senderId' });
UserModel.hasMany(TransactionModel, { as: 'receivedTransactions', foreignKey: 'receiverId' });
UserModel.belongsToMany(TransactionModel, { as: 'transactionLikes', through: 'UserLike', foreignKey: 'userId' });
TransactionModel.belongsTo(UserModel, { as: 'receiver' });
TransactionModel.belongsTo(UserModel, { as: 'sender' });
TransactionModel.belongsToMany(UserModel, { as: 'likers', through: 'UserLike', foreignKey: 'transactionId' });
```

Which means a user has many received and sent transactions and each user can "like" many transactions.

How can I delete a transaction and remove all associations (receiver, sender, liker)? I don't want to delete the users too.

I would also like to update the User Model which is defined like this, in order to add an "email" property:

```
const UserModel = db.define('user', {
   id: { type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true, primaryKey: true },
   firstName: { type: Sequelize.STRING  },
   lastName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
   username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: {
    args: true,
    msg: USERNAME_IS_TAKEN,
   },
 }
```

How can I update the model? What will happen to the existing instances?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This is not so much a PostgreSQL question than an inquiry into your ORM of choice. What you’re looking for is a foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE / SET NULL / DO NOTHING, but I’m not sure what kind of SQL is it generating.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this tutorial](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html) your M:N relation should work as you expect it out of the box:

> For n:m, the default for both is CASCADE. This means, that if you delete or update a row from one side of an n:m association, all the rows in the join table referencing that row will also be deleted or updated.

Further more, to enforce the `CASCADE` behavior you may also pass `onDelete` option to the association calls. Something like this should do the trick:

```
TransactionModel.belongsToMany(UserModel, { as: 'likers', through: 'UserLike', foreignKey: 'transactionId', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
```

Adding an email property to the User Model should be as easy as that:

```
const UserModel = db.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: { type: Sequelize.STRING  },
    lastName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: {
            args: true,
            msg: USERNAME_IS_TAKEN,
        }
    },
    email: { type: Sequelize.STRING }
});
```